# How to fix Cross Site Scripting security warning in rails when using html_safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I used brakeman for generating scanning reports in my application. It generated many Cross Site Scripting security warnings with High Confidence in my reports/show page:

> Unescaped model attribute near line 104:
>   Report.find(params[:id]).remarks

I have seen in the link but couldn't fix. Please help. And this is the line in show page which I am facing error:

```
<%= @report.remarks.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brakeman warns about any cases of potential user input being output without HTML escaping. Values from the database count as "potential user input".

If you are expecting `remarks` on reports to contain HTML that you wish the browser to interpret *as HTML*, then you must use `html_safe` and you are responsible for ensuring the HTML is safe - perhaps by calling [`sanitize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) or `strip_tags`. If you are not expecting `remarks` to contain HTML, then remove the call to `html_safe`.

The `html_safe` call essentially tells Rails "this string is safe, do not escape it." If that is what you intend, then you can [ignore these warnings](http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/ignoring_false_positives/).

Comment: Did the trick, I wrote `<%= sanitize @report.remarks.html_safe %>`

Comment: I'm curious, why not just `<%= @report.remarks %>`? That would be safer and simpler.

Comment: Actually it is a maintenance project. The previous developer wrote a comment before this as **To keep remarks field safer**. So, without any modification I continued with html_safe  :)